# Is there any way to exclude branches from showing in GitK?

Tags: git, branch, gitk

Sometimes when I use GitK there's a load of commits on branches I'm not concerned with and they tend get in the way of what I'm doing.

It would be nice to be able to specify which branches I want, or specify which branches I want to exclude.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does `gitk branch1 branch2 ...` not work for you? Normally `gitk` only shows the current branch, unless you `gitk --all` (although it will still annotate any other branch/tag pointers that happen to be in the ancestry of your current branch; it will also show branches that were merged into your branch, up to the last merge, but not commits on those branches made since the last merge).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can specify which branches you want by specifying them as arguments to the `gitk` command. I'm assuming that you're already using `--all`, but you might be interested to know that there's also a `--not` flag...although it has some side effects and is not too useful in most circumstances.

Consider a repository that looks like this:

```
git checkout feature-B
gitk --all
```

[image]

If you specify no arguments, you get just the branch you're on:

```
gitk
```

[image]

If you specify multiple branches, you get those branches, and the branches that are fully merged (i.e. they don't "stick out"). For example, here I have `feature-B`, `feature-C`, along with the fully merged `feature-A` and `master`, but no `feature-D`:

```
gitk feature-B feature-C
```

[image]

Finally, you can use the `--not` flag to ignore a branch. *However*, since a branch refers to all the commits that lead up to it, the `--not` flag will ignore commits that are on the branches that you *do* specify.

```
gitk feature-B --not feature-D
gitk --all --not feature-D feature-C
```

Both of these will give you:

[image]

Here, the commits `Initial commit` and `1` are ignored, because they belonged to branch `feature-D`. Commit `2` is also ignored for the same reason, but is shown as an empty commit, since it would be incorrect and misleading to show commit `3` as the initial commit in the branch. This flag can be helpful sometimes, but I don't usually find myself using it.

Comment: Your `--not` example is a little confusing, since `gitk feature-B` wouldn't show feature-D anyway, so adding a `--not` there would only be useful if you were *intending* to get the result you showed. A better example of your criticism might be `gitk --all --not feature-D`.

Comment: Great point, thanks. I've added `gitk --all --not feature-D feature-C` to my answer, since it yields the same result as `gitk feature-B --not feature-D`, and does a better job expressing the oddities of `--not`.

Comment: Haha, clever way to avoid editing your images :) BTW, I was curious about if there was a workaround to the `--not` oddity, so I posted this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20979339/430128

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks for all the effort you put into it. It really helps.