# Use git rev-list to exclude a branch, but keep common ancestors with the included branches

Tags: git, version-control

Say I have the following git repo:

[image: --all]

I want to specify a git rev-list of all branches (`--all`) but excluding a given branch (say, `feature-D`), but I want to *show* common ancestors of `feature-D` and the other branches i.e. commit `Initial` and `1`.

If I try `git rev-list --all ^feature-D` commits `Initial` and `1` are excluded:

[image: --all ^feature-D]

Of course I can list all branches except for `feature-D` explicitly (`git rev-list feature-A feature-B feature-C`) to get what I want:

[image: feature-A feature-B feature-C]

But is there a way to specify a rev-list that obtains the prior result, only by reference to `feature-D`?

(Note that this question was inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20978568/430128)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit indirect but seems to work.  We start with:

```
git rev-list --no-walk --all ^feature-D
```

which produces a list of all SHA-1s directly pointed to by any ref (including tags, branches, stashes, etc; use `--branches` rather than `--all` if you want only branches) *except* those under `feature-D`:

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
* 74e0d3e (feature-D) 7
* 0448a13 6
| * ab3a532 (feature-C) 5
|/  
| * 50477c7 (feature-B) 4
| * 28717e5 3
|/  
* 2ac5cef (HEAD, master, feature-A) 2
* c6a10b4 1
* 76c511f Initial
$ git rev-list --no-walk --all ^feature-D
ab3a5320e792e945b896634d667df5ace4a8b871
50477c7b28b5479587e45fe97292e71a3c0851c5
28717e5628ad111e8b68323dc485fd190a780446
```

Now we feed this to `git rev-list` *again* to get the history-walking:

```
$ git rev-list --no-walk --all ^feature-D | git rev-list --stdin
ab3a5320e792e945b896634d667df5ace4a8b871
50477c7b28b5479587e45fe97292e71a3c0851c5
28717e5628ad111e8b68323dc485fd190a780446
2ac5cefb971c7f5c5be33a77a6db71127982eaf5
c6a10b4568136d65b31b7e262ef7745db4962460
76c511fcf38076e0ea98db73a4923de6fc806b4a
```

Pipe that to `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --stdin` to verify that those are the right commits, if eyeballing it is not sufficiently clear:

```
* ab3a532 (feature-C) 5
| * 50477c7 (feature-B) 4
| * 28717e5 3
|/  
* 2ac5cef (HEAD, master, feature-A) 2
* c6a10b4 1
* 76c511f Initial
```

(and one side note: if using `git log --oneline --decorate --graph` to view your middle version, i.e., `git rev-list --all ^feature-D`, you need to add `--boundary` to see commit 2; gitk probably adds `--boundary` to make it show up, not that I tested this).

There's a defect here: if `feature-C` and `feature-B` branches did not exist you would not see commits 2 through Initial.  I'm not sure, but I think the only real fix for this is to use something much more complex.

---

Edit: ok, not *that* much more complex.  Start with `git for-each-ref` to print branches.  Pipe through `grep -v ^feature-D$` to eliminate `feature-D`.  Now you have all the branches you want as arguments:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate $(git for-each-ref \
>  --format '%(refname:short)' refs/heads/ | grep -v '^feature-D$')
* ab3a532 (feature-C) 5
| * 50477c7 (feature-B) 4
| * 28717e5 3
|/  
* 2ac5cef (master, feature-A) 2
* c6a10b4 1
* 76c511f Initial
```

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting: `git rev-list --all ^feature-D | git log --oneline --decorate --graph --stdin` seems to do the right thing on its own. Presumably because log basically does the same thing as `git rev-list --stdin` in order to display the log.

Comment: Yes, `git log` does a parent walk, and the extra walk "re-inserts" commits 2-through-Initial, just as it does for my somewhat defective first-part-of-answer.

Comment: Your second answer is good, but somewhat violates the spirit of my question. I already knew that I could get what I wanted if I explicitly listed all the branches except the one I wanted -- you just specified how to do that programmatically which is good but not *really* what I was looking for. Still, its correct. I'll leave the answer unaccepted for now to see what others come up with, and if there is nothing I'll vote you up and accept.

Comment: Your first answer is useful too, btw. Thanks.

Comment: Heh, yes, that's why I was attempting to do it without extracting all the branch names.  It doesn't seem to be easy at least, as the only thing that will stop `git rev-list` from walking "too far" down the feature-D path is `--ancestry-path` but that requires naming the `master` or `feature-A` branches.  (You can use `git rev-list --ancestry-path feature-D --not <all branches except feature-D>` to do this but now we're finding all branches programmatically again.)

Answer (score 2):

### Simple solution

Instead of listing all branches explicitly (either manually or with a complicated program), we can use a regex to include `--all` refs and `--exclude` a specific one.

According to the man page, the `--all` flag will

> Pretend as if all the refs in `refs/` are listed on the command line as `<commit>`.

Ideally, we would pretend that all of the refs in `refs/` *except for feature-D* are listed on the command line as `<commit>`.

So to exclude `feature-D` we can use `--exclude=refs/heads/feature-D --all`.

*Note: The flag order is important.*

---

### A note for gitk users:

(Probably relevant since the OP image includes a gitk screenshot.)

I originally came across this question while trying to ignore a branch in gitk and I noticed a small gitk bug that my answer above will trigger.  If gitk is started with the above flags, then everything works fine.  However, if after starting gitk the the view is modified from within the GUI menu, the flag ordering seems to get changed and cause the branch to reappear.  (This will happen if the OK button is pressed even if no actual changes are made.)  I was unable to figure out how to fix this while still using the `--all` flag, but I have a workaround.

Instead of using `--all`, we can use `--branches=* --tags=* --remotes=* stash`.

So to exclude `feature-D`, we can modify this to say `--exclude=refs/heads/feature-D --branches=* --tags=* --remotes=* stash`.

We can then start gitk using `gitk --exclude=refs/heads/feature-D --branches=* --tags=* --remotes=* stash` and editing the view through the GUI no longer causes this bug.