# Tell gitk to ignore all branches that match pattern

Tags: git, gitk

Suppose I have some branches with names beginning with `inactive-`.  As their names suggest, these branches are inactive; I'm keeping around for archival purposes.

I want to tell `gitk` to ignore those branches, even if I also pass it the `--all` flag.  Is there a way to do this?

Alternatively, is there some other convenient way to tell `gitk` to include all branches *except* those whose name matches `inactive-*`?

---

P.S.  I did try

```
gitk --branches='!inactive-*'
```

...and variations thereof, but none worked.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977520/is-there-any-way-to-exclude-branches-from-showing-in-gitk

Comment: One workaround that I could imagine is to make a clone of the repository in which the inactive branches are kept, and to delete them in the "active" repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no really convenient way to do this.

Here's a slightly inconvenient way to achieve a similar result to "`--all` except for `invalid-*`":

```
gitk $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads | grep -v '^inactive-')
```

That is, we use `git for-each-ref` to find all branch names (everything in `refs/heads/*`), then use `grep -v` to discard those whose name starts with `inactive-`.  The resulting list is the set of arguments to `gitk`.

(You could modify `gitk` to do this fairly easily, since `gitk` is just a gigantic Tcl/Tk script.)

Answer (score 3):

2014: as [j6t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6868543/j6t) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211882/tell-gitk-to-ignore-all-branches-that-match-pattern/76742553?noredirect=1#comment135295751_76742553), `gitk` already provide a solution (requested and documented by jt6):

```
gitk --exclude=inactive-\* --branches
```

Before Git 1.9 (Q4 2013), people often wished a way to tell "[`git log --branches`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/10167eb251e177349eebf24650d3c0cc26bd0d75/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L132)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---branchesltpatterngt))</sup> (and "[`git log --remotes --not --branches`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/10167eb251e177349eebf24650d3c0cc26bd0d75/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L144)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---remotesltpatterngt))</sup>) to exclude some local branches from the expansion of "`--branches`" (similarly for "`--tags`", "`--all`" and "`--glob=<pattern>`").
Now they have one.

See [commit 9dc01bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9dc01bf0631b51dfe497d57942a9085e0808e205), [commit ff32d34](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff32d3420a550d3811e745af7f2ccc77fb026b7b), [commit 751a2ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/751a2ac6edfbc803b9ed7c48d2d1fc54c97cc64c) (01 Nov 2013), and [commit e7b432c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e7b432c521b0177e86eaecd2bd16906b9fc53e10) (30 Aug 2013) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 574d370](https://github.com/git/git/commit/574d370b0633a89f7d62ec4eac08228b26eea06f) (02 Sep 2013) by [Johannes Sixt (`j6t`)](https://github.com/j6t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 10167eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10167eb251e177349eebf24650d3c0cc26bd0d75), 05 Dec 2013)</sup>

> ### [`rev-parse`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9dc01bf0631b51dfe497d57942a9085e0808e205): introduce --exclude= to tame wildcards

> Teach "`rev-parse`" the same "I'm going to glob, but omit the ones that match these patterns" feature as "rev-list".

`git rev-parse` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9dc01bf0631b51dfe497d57942a9085e0808e205/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt#L158-L171):

> ### `--exclude=<glob-pattern>`
>
> Do not include refs matching '' that the next `--all`,
> `--branches`, `--tags`, `--remotes`, or `--glob` would otherwise
> consider. Repetitions of this option accumulate exclusion patterns
> up to the next `--all`, `--branches`, `--tags`, `--remotes`, or
> `--glob` option (other options or arguments do not clear
> accumlated patterns).
>
> The patterns given should not begin with `refs/heads`, `refs/tags`, or
> `refs/remotes` when applied to `--branches`, `--tags`, or `--remotes`,
> respectively, and they must begin with `refs/` when applied to `--glob`
> or `--all`. If a trailing '/{asterisk}' is intended, it must be given
> explicitly.

---

But, if you have to use `git for-each-ref`, to echo [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek)'s 2017 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42213967/6309):

2023 (6+ years later): Yes, there is now a convenient way to do this

With Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), enumerating refs in the packed-refs file, while excluding refs that match certain patterns, has been optimized.

And that means you can use `git for-each-ref` with the new `--exclude` option:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" --exclude="inactive-" refs/heads
```

(The pattern follows [`fnmatch`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html) though, it is not a true regex)

So:

```
gitk $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" --exclude="inactive-" refs/heads)
```

See [commit 284c55d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/284c55deb53921457929ca2afe231c48e6cada85), [commit b571fb9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b571fb98008b485bfc6f7d6538b79a7e92d731f4), [commit 311bfe1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/311bfe18ce8563d0b1b571e9dc9eb35b97de3790), [commit b9f7daa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9f7daa6ef52ad8894b5f730eaee0599668d66d5), [commit bf1377a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf1377a12b904a01692be9f0fd5746c7e71c8878) (10 Jul 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 98456ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98456eff08069696708b24ab4f1152f06a3b47f9), [commit 18b6b1b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18b6b1b5c57bb4d1b2730b664fb1660b006ef7d3), [commit cc2a1f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc2a1f98ac1042c7cca0ecedd6d57819c6b8e02e), [commit 15af64d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15af64dcfd176b65cdb938e9b7f27adb8aabffa4), [commit e6bf24d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6bf24d39a6a85e0a2257f22bffc09b9df749b4a), [commit c45841f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c45841fff8f444cc61cecd42e5d2032844ecbe24), [commit c489f47](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c489f47a649da8984a2240032e1d819e9a80ea2a), [commit 59c35fa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/59c35fac54054b3f781b0275eac7d7c54468f0d5), [commit d22d941](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d22d941ac08aa31266bb0b38d78c79c3ffdc4f86), [commit b269ac5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b269ac53c07aa46d5a88d05dac8216d189e69a50), [commit 8255dd8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8255dd8a3dce094129690d17595dc822171d1e61) (10 Jul 2023) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 39fe402](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39fe402d6727efb6c98ddca19fae1f094ffaa6b3), 21 Jul 2023)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/for-each-ref.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8255dd8a3dce094129690d17595dc822171d1e61): add `--exclude` option
>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> When using `for-each-ref`, it is sometimes convenient for the caller to be able to exclude certain parts of the references.
>
> For example, if there are many `refs/__hidden__/*` references, the caller may want to emit all references *except* the hidden ones.
> Currently, the only way to do this is to post-process the output, like:
>
> ```
> $ git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' | grep -v '^refs/hidden/'
> ```
>
> Which is do-able, but requires processing a potentially large quantity of references.
>
> Teach [`git for-each-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8255dd8a3dce094129690d17595dc822171d1e61/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref))</sup> a new `--exclude=<pattern>` option, which excludes references from the results if they match one or more excluded patterns.
>
> This patch provides a naive implementation where the `ref_filter` still sees all references (including ones that it will discard) and is left to check whether each reference matches any excluded pattern(s) before emitting them.
>
> By culling out references we know the caller doesn't care about, we can avoid allocating memory for their storage, as well as spending time sorting the output (among other things).
> Even the naive implementation provides a significant speed-up on a modified copy of linux.git (that has a hidden ref pointing at each commit):
>
> ```
> $ hyperfine \
>   'git.compile for-each-ref --format="%(objectname) %(refname)" | grep -vE "[0-9a-f]{40} refs/pull/"' \
>   'git.compile for-each-ref --format="%(objectname) %(refname)" --exclude refs/pull/'
> Benchmark 1: git.compile for-each-ref --format="%(objectname) %(refname)" | grep -vE "[0-9a-f]{40} refs/pull/"
>   Time (mean ± σ):     820.1 ms ±   2.0 ms    [User: 703.7 ms, System: 152.0 ms]
>   Range (min … max):   817.7 ms … 823.3 ms    10 runs
>
> Benchmark 2: git.compile for-each-ref --format="%(objectname) %(refname)" --exclude refs/pull/
>   Time (mean ± σ):     106.6 ms ±   1.1 ms    [User: 99.4 ms, System: 7.1 ms]
>   Range (min … max):   104.7 ms … 109.1 ms    27 runs
>
> Summary
>   'git.compile for-each-ref --format="%(objectname) %(refname)" --exclude refs/pull/' ran
>     7.69 ± 0.08 times faster than 'git.compile for-each-ref --format="%(objectname) %(refname)" | grep -vE "[0-9a-f]{40} refs/pull/"'
> ```
>
> Subsequent patches will improve on this by avoiding visiting excluded sections of the `packed-refs` file in certain cases.

`git for-each-ref` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8255dd8a3dce094129690d17595dc822171d1e61/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt#L106-L110):

> ### `--exclude=<pattern>`
>
> If one or more patterns are given, only refs which do not match
> any excluded pattern(s) are shown. Matching is done using the
> same rules as `<pattern>` above.

Comment: Why that `git for-each-ref` complexity? `gitk --exclude=inactive-\* --branches` has worked since the inception of `--exclude` in [commit 10167eb251e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10167eb251e177349eebf24650d3c0cc26bd0d75) (2014). This was in fact the use-case for which I asked for that feature.

Comment: @j6t I agree. This is just to illustrate the new git for-each feature

Comment: @j6t I have edited the answer to include first your Git 1.9 `git rev-parse --exclude` feature.

Comment: Thanks, but the feature was implemented by Junio; I only wrote the text in the manual pages.